# What happened to version 1.2.8 of the logger gem?

Tags: ruby, logging, rubygems

The logger gem, which has been at version 1.2.8 for 7.5 years, was yanked from rubygems.org today and replaced with version 1.2.7:

https://rubygems.org/gems/logger/versions/1.2.8

This library was not a gem before 1.2.8. The gemspec was added on 2011-05-11:

https://github.com/nahi/logger/commit/af96ca8fbf9ca1a20812a222c27d5c1ccf5d297e

There has never been an official release of a 1.2.7 version, as told by the release history on GitHub:

https://github.com/nahi/logger/releases

There have been no commits to this repo for more than 6 years. If a 1.2.7 version of the library was built as a gem, it was done so from a different source repo. I see no evidence that the nahi repo has been superseded by any other repo.

Does anyone know what happened? At this point, we're going to set the source for this gem to the 1.2.8 release commit on GitHub until there's some official word on this.

EDIT: My question isn't about whether or not the logger gem still needs to be maintained. If that were the case, why publish a new version yesterday? And why go backwards in version numbering? And why is there no record of these changes in the repo? There are big differences in what was marked (but not released) as 1.2.7 back in 2008 (and remember, 1.2.8 was published as a gem for the first time 3 years after that in 2011) and what was published yesterday as 1.2.7. We rely on a gem that requires this gem. Sure, we'll reevaluate whether or not that requirement is still true, but the circumstances around yanking 1.2.8 and replacing it with something that has no (established or announced) record of change is odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just saw this too as I'm doing a clean deploy to my web host. I've raised an issue on the github repo https://github.com/nahi/logger/issues/3

Comment: The answer to my question is contained in your issue request. I recommend people follow that link to see the details. In short, nothing nefarious happened, but I think many people believe it was a questionable decision to yank the gem instead of publishing a new one (which has now been done with version 1.3.0).